# modelsim prompt wildcard suggestions/autocomplete disappeared

Tags: modelsim

Normally when I type a command in modelsim, if I have a star * in the command, it lists the available files that match that wildcard. The most common one I do is

```
>do *.do
```

And then a window pops up showing all the files with the extension *.do, and I can use the arrow keys to select the file I want to perform the command on.

While this suggestions window was open, I accidentally clicked the X and it closed. Now, I can't figure out how to get that suggestion window to reappear. Even after restarting modelsim, I just get nothing at all when I type the same command. I did do a sanity check and make sure I actually have *.do files in the  same directory...

How do I get that autocomplete/wildcard window back?  I can't seem to locate it in the toolbar windows.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on the Google Forums:

Go to Tools > Edit Preferences. Then select the By Name tab and expand Main. Scroll down to EnableCommandHelp and set it's value to 1.

[Google Forms post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modelsim-pe-student-edition/n8MtjHQKGmQ)